# How can I dismount a truecrypt partition over ssh in windows 7

Tags: ssh, cygwin, truecrypt

I'm having trouble dismounting a truecrypt container, in windows 7, over ssh.

When opening a cygwin terminal on the local computer (where truecrypt is running and the partition is mounted), I can do this and it works as expected:

```
/cygdrive/c/Program\ Files/TrueCrypt/TrueCrypt.exe /q /d n
```

However when I do this:

```
$ ssh computer "/cygdrive/c/Program\ Files/TrueCrypt/TrueCrypt.exe /q /d n"
Enter passphrase for key '/home/user/.ssh/id_rsa':
stty: standard input: Inappropriate ioctl for device
```

I first get the stty error message shown above. On the computer running truecrypt the drive letter n disappears from the gui completely. The partion seems to get dismounted, however I cant mount to that letter again without restarting the computer which is annoying.

Is there a way around this problem?

Answer (score 0):

The `Inappropriate ioctl for device` is caused by a shell startup script (either yours or one under `/etc`) executing an `stty` command.  Since there is no pseudo-terminal allocated for one-shot ssh commands, the `stty` command fails when it tries to manipulate the non-existent terminal that it expects to find on `stdin`.  BTW, this is almost always innocuous and can be ignored.  As to why you can't mount a TrueCrypt filesystem to that drive letter again without rebooting, I have to ask: are you mounting over an SSH connection or from within the GUI?